# Observable Lists merge to a single observable List in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

I am building an Android app which gathering data with a specific argument. The app is developed in Java/Kotlin and based on RxJava.

```
class Cars constructor(val carsData: CarsData) {

  fun getCars(): Observable<List<Car>> {
    return listOf(
        carsData.getCar("toyota")
            .flatMap { Observable.from(it)}
            .distinct { it.productId }
            .toSortedList()
          ,
        carsData.getCar("chevrolet")
            .flatMap { Observable.from(it)}
            .distinct { it.productId }
            .toSortedList(),
        carsData.getCar("cadillac")
            .flatMap { Observable.from(it)}
            .distinct { it.productId }
            .toSortedList())

}
```

I want to return an `Observable<List<Car>>`. Any call to `getCar` is returning an `Observable<List<Car>>`. By default, I have an issue because I am returning an `Observable<List<Observable<List<Car>>>` because I need to extract the data first to merge everything.

Any idea, how to make it works? the code above is not working, because it's complaining about type issue and I assume it's linked to the mix of Observable.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to return an `Observable` that will emit these 3 lists in sequence, you can use [`Observable.merge`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html) or [`Observable.concat`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/concat.html) depending on whether you want to preserve their order:

```
return Observable.merge(
    carsData.getCar("toyota")
            .flatMap { Observable.from(it) }
            .distinct { it.productId }
            .toSortedList(),
    carsData.getCar("chevrolet")
            .flatMap { Observable.from(it) }
            .distinct { it.productId }
            .toSortedList(),
    carsData.getCar("cadillac")
            .flatMap { Observable.from(it) }
            .distinct { it.productId }
            .toSortedList()
)
```